# Eslint Using Determined Function from another file

Tags: javascript, eslint

I use airbnb-base eslint rule.
I have a function in a.js

```
const test = () => {
    console.log('OK');
}
```

And in b.js

```
import '../scripts/a.js';
test()
```

But in eslint error is **no-unused-vars** in a.js and **no-undef** in b.js.

I don't want to change the rules of ESLint and I would like to find an elegant way to get rid of these error messages.
How should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Just configure it. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring Furthermore, it's not really best practice to do that anyway. If you're exporting your variables then you won't get those errors.

Comment: all you need to do is to export test and import it like `export const test = () => {
    console.log('OK');
}` and `import  { test } from '../scripts/a.js';`

Comment: There is an error in 'export const test = () => { console.log('OK');  ':Prefer default export. (import/prefer-default-export) How could I solve it?

Comment: You might find this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062416/eslint-determine-globals-from-another-file#tab-top